# Syntax error 1084 in Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am getting 2 syntax errors out of this. I am new to Flash. How can I fix this?

```
var paddlepos:int = paddle.x.position

if; (paddlepos > 253) 
{
    paddle.x.postition = 253;
}
```

Syntax errors:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 28 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before leftbrace.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 27 1084: Syntax error: expecting leftparen before semicolon.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors:

1. Your `if` statement doesn't need a semicolon:

   ```
   if (paddlepos > 253)
   ```
2. When referencing paddle's position, access the `x` property, as in:

   ```
   var paddlepos:Number = paddle.x;
   paddle.x = 253;
   ```
3. Terminate your first line with a semicolon, and note `x` should be `Number`:

   ```
   var paddlepos:Number = paddle.x;
   ```

This code could be reduced to:

```
if (paddle.x > 253) 
{
    paddle.x = 253;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error on Line 27 tells you the exact reason.  "Expecting leftparen before semicolon."

Move that semicolon from your "if;" to the end of your first line of code.